# Update method throws an exception, because the entity is already tracked

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a problem with EF Core 5 that is really getting me down.
FYI, LazyLoadingProxies are used (something else that just gives me a headache, but well, different topic).

Information for the code below:
Service: A service per entity, contains all CRUD operations into the database and other methods if needed.
Workflow: Uses multiple services at once to perform certain operations (e.g. create product -> create product folder -> save product).

Problem:
I have an entity "Product" which contains the following update method which is used to update the properties of the entity with those of another object:

```
public override void Update(Product source)
{
    // Properties
    AnnualPrice = source.AnnualPrice;
    ...

    // Relations
    var sourceRelatedProductIds = source.RelatedWithProductIds.Where(x => x != Id);
    if (sourceRelatedProductIds.Count() != 0)
    {
        RelatedWithProducts.Clear();
        foreach (var relatedWithProduct in ctx.Set<Product>().Where(x => source.RelatedWithProductIds.Contains(x.Id)).AsNoTracking())
        {
            RelatedWithProducts.Add(relatedWithProduct);
        }
    }

    var oldShortDescriptions = ShortDescriptions.ToList(); <--- EXCEPTION
    ShortDescriptions.Clear();
    foreach (var shortDescription in source.ShortDescriptions)
    {
        shortDescription.Id = oldShortDescriptions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Culture == shortDescription.Culture)?.Id ?? 0;
        ShortDescriptions.Add(shortDescription);
    }

    ...
}
```

In the line with the arrow and "Exception", I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Product' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'
```

In itself, I understand what the exception is trying to tell me. My problem is that I can't find the reason for it anywhere. Because as far as I can tell, the product with ID 1 can't be tracked yet.

Of course, the problem is not in the update method, but before it, so here is the rest of the code.

ProductController.Update:

```
[HttpPut("update")]
public IActionResult Update(C.Product[] products)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return UnprocessableEntity(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors));
    }

    var dbProducts = products.Select(ToDatabase).ToArray(); <--- Just converts the given client model into a Database model

    var result = productWorkflow.Update(dbProducts); <--- Calls a workflow class, NOT the update method of the entity

    return CoreToActionResultConverter.ToActionResult<Db.Product>(result);
}
```

ProductWorkflow.Update:

```
public ResultBase Update(params Product[] products)
{
    var result = productService.AddOrUpdate(products); <--- This calls the Service CRUD AddOrUpdate method
    if (result is not ServiceResult<Product>)
    {
        return result;
    }

    return new ServiceResult<Product>(ResultType.AddedOrUpdated);
}
```

ProductService.AddOrUpdate:

```
public virtual ResultBase AddOrUpdate(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    var currentEntities = new List<TEntity>();

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var currentEntity = Get(entity.Id); <--- This line is the only one where I could imagine that it is already tracked here. The problem is only that it does not work ONLY with the workflow. If I call my AddOrUpdate method from the controller, which directly calls THIS method, it works (although this line is just executed the same way).
        if (currentEntity == null)
        {
            currentEntity = Ctx.CreateProxy<TEntity>();
            Ctx.Attach(currentEntity);
        }

        if (currentEntity != entity)
        {
            currentEntity.Update(entity);
        }

        currentEntities.Add(currentEntity);
    }

    Ctx.AddRange(currentEntities.Where(x => x.Id == 0));
    Ctx.UpdateRange(currentEntities.Where(x => x.Id != 0));

    try
    {
        Ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        // Commented out the error handling to remove unnecessary things for the post
    }

    return new ServiceResult<TEntity>(ServiceResult.ResultType.AddedOrUpdated, currentEntities);
}
```

Comment: What is `ShortDescriptions`?

Comment: Its just a virtual ICollection<Translation>, where "Translation" is an entity, which just contains 2 properties, string Culture and string Value

Comment: Btw, virtual, because of the use of LazyLoadingProxies

Comment: Too much isn't clear here. In what class is this `Update` method? If it's in an entity class, why does it even have an `Update` method? Where does the context `ctx` come from? What is its life cycle? How is it used?

Comment: Yes, the update method is in the entity. It will potentially come out from there later, for now it's in there. Removed the "ctx" in the update method, was just for testing. Otherwise "Ctx" (in case of the ProductService.AddOrUpdate method) comes from the constructor, via dependency injection. All services and workflows are added as "Scoped". What do you mean by "How is it used"? ProductController.Update calls ProductWorkflow.Update which calls ProductService.Update which calls the Update method of the entity before the changes are saved to the db afterwards.

Comment: One more additional piece of information:
If I set a breakpoint in the line that throws the exception and debug the whole thing, then everything works. But only with the breakpoint, not without. My guess is that the breakpoint evaluates the entity (which is lazy loaded). However, the entity is then tracked in any case, so I do not understand why no exception is thrown.

Comment: Found the issue, updated the post and answer follows

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it was not on the line where the exception was thrown, but before.
In my Product.Update() method (the first code snippet), I get the Related Products by ID and add them to the list (Simply a Many to Many relationship, from Product <--> Product). When calling Update, I specified ID 1 in the RelatedProductIds, however the entity itself also has ID 1, so it references itself. I have now just fixed that by omitting the ID, if the same as the object itself.
This still doesn't explain why it works with a breakpoint, because it's still tracked in that case (or not tracked, since I'm using AsNoTracking(), but good).